# Computing the cotangent complex of morphisms of perfect complexes

Tags: derived-categories, deformation-theory, infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

In Lurie's Spectral Algebraic Geometry the cotangent complex of $\textbf{Perf}$ is computed as $ \Sigma^{-1}( \mathscr{F} \otimes \mathscr{F}^\vee)$ for some universal $\mathscr{F} \in \text{Qcoh}(\textbf{Perf})$. I was curious about how to compute the cotangent complex of $\textbf{Perf}_{\Delta^1}: = Fun(\Delta^1, \textbf{Perf})$?

I seems like SAG 19.2.3.4 should be relevant but it looks like what this proposition computes is the cotangent complex of the map $\textbf{Perf}_{\Delta^1} \times_{\textbf{Perf} \times \textbf{Perf}} Spec(R) \rightarrow Spec(R)$ and I'm not sure how to extract the the cotangent complex of $\textbf{Perf}_{\Delta^1}$ out of it.

Comment: For the universal morphism $E \to F$ of perfect complexes on $\mathbf{Perf}_{\Delta^1}$, it's just the cone (or if you prefer, homotopy cofibre) of the obvious map $(E\otimes E^{\vee}) \oplus (F\otimes F^{\vee}) \to F\otimes E^{\vee}$.

Comment: @JonPridham thanks for your answer! It would be really helpful to me if you could say a bit where the map $(E \otimes E^\vee) \oplus (F \otimes F^\vee) \rightarrow F \otimes E^\vee $ comes from. It looks to me like it comes from induced triangle on cotangent complexes of the map $\textbf{Perf}_{\Delta^1} \rightarrow \textbf{Perf} \times \textbf{Perf}$ but I don't see it. Sorry for being slow.

Comment: It's easiest to understand these by dualising and looking at tangent functors. $\mathrm{End}(E)[1]$ and $\mathrm{End}(F)[1]$ describe first order deformations of $E$ and $F$, and then the term in $\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)$ checks compatibility between those deformations and the morphism $E \to F$.

Comment: @JonPridham Thanks a lot for this, I think it is clearer now to me!